# Spring Cloud Stream - How to avoid sending messages to non-target brokers

Tags: spring-cloud-stream, spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka

I have a kafka producer application with the following configuration.

```yaml
spring:
  main:
    banner-mode: off
  application:
    name: sample-app

  cloud:
    stream:
      function:
        definition: sendEvents;jsonEvents

      binders:
        kafka1:
          type: kafka
          environment:
            spring.cloud.stream.kafka.binder:
              brokers:
                - 'localhost:29092'

        kafka2:
          type: kafka
          environment:
            spring.cloud.stream.kafka.binder:
              brokers:
                - 'localhost:29093'

      bindings:
        sendEvents-out-0:
          binder: kafka1
          destination: send_events
          contentType: application/json
        jsonEvents-out-0:
          binder: kafka2
          destination: json_events
          contentType: application/json
        consumer-in-0:
          binder: kafka1
          group: ${spring.application.name}
          destination: send_events
        consumer2-in-0:
          binder: kafka2
          group: ${spring.application.name}
          destination: json_events
```

```java
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.cloud.stream.function.StreamBridge;
import org.springframework.http.MediaType;
import org.springframework.messaging.Message;
import org.springframework.messaging.MessageHeaders;
import org.springframework.messaging.support.MessageBuilder;
import org.springframework.util.MimeTypeUtils;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

import lombok.extern.slf4j.Slf4j;

@RestController
@RequestMapping(path = "/{datasource}/{topicName}")
@Slf4j
public class MainController
{

  @Autowired
  StreamBridge streamBridge;

  @PostMapping(consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
  public Map postMessage(@PathVariable(name = "datasource") String source,
                         @PathVariable(name = "topicName") String topic,
                         @RequestBody Object body)
  {

    Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<>();
    log.info("what is source " + source);

    log.info("what is topic " + topic);
    map.put("source", source);
    map.put("topic", topic);

    Message<Map<String, String>> message = MessageBuilder.withPayload(map)
      .setHeader(MessageHeaders.CONTENT_TYPE, MimeTypeUtils.APPLICATION_JSON)
      .setHeader(MessageHeaders.ERROR_CHANNEL, "error_channel")
      .build();

    log.info("postMessage");
    if (source.equalsIgnoreCase("send")) {
      streamBridge.send("sendEvents-out-0", message);
    } else {
      
      streamBridge.send("jsonEvents-out-0", message);
    }
    return map;


  }
}
```

The app is a simple `spring-boot-starter-webflux` application. When a request is received, it will send the body to the corresponding Kafka brokers. Messages in one broker are not supposed to be in another broker. `StreamBridge` is used to send messages to different bindings.

However, when I tested the application, I found that the message only supposed to be in kafka2's (jsonEvents-out-0) could also be found in kafka1 in the same topic (json_events). How could I completely avoid kafka1 storing messages supposed to be in kafka2 only?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution. I can bind the autowired BindingServiceProperty to the bean and get the BinderName by BindingServiceProperty

```java
bindingName = "sendEvents-out-0";

String binder = this.bindingServiceProperties.getBindingProperties(bindingName).getBinder();

streamBridge.send(bindingName, binder, message);
```

In this case, the message will not be sent to the default kafka cluster.